# Oracle Library UTL_XML_LIB Must be Declared

Tags: c, oracle, plsql

I am trying to understand a couple of things:

1.) Is there any documentation about all of the Libraries that exist in Oracle. Specifically the procedures/functions that are available in each?

2.) I am trying to use library `SYS.UTL_XML_LIB` using the following code:

```sql
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE utl_xml_parse_query (
         in_current_userid IN NUMBER,
         in_schema_name    IN VARCHAR2,
         in_query          IN CLOB,
         in_result         IN OUT NOCOPY CLOB
      ) IS
         LANGUAGE C 
         LIBRARY sys.UTL_XML_LIB 
         NAME "kuxParseQuery"
         WITH CONTEXT PARAMETERS (
            CONTEXT,
            in_current_userid OCINUMBER,
            in_current_userid INDICATOR,
            in_schema_name    OCISTRING,
            in_schema_name    INDICATOR,
            in_query          OCILOBLOCATOR,
            in_query          INDICATOR,
            in_result         OCILOBLOCATOR,
            in_result         INDICATOR
         );
```

I get an error saying that `SYS.UTIL_XML_LIB` must be declared.

I have been granted execute on `SYS.UTIL_XML_LIB`

I can see the library in `ALL_LIBRARIES` and I can see the grant of execute to the ROLE that has been granted to my id.

Is there something I am missing? Does the `EXECUTE` grant need to be directly to my id? Am I invoking the library incorrectly?

I am looking everywhere for something that will tell me what other functionality is in the library but cannot find anything other than the example above. Any help is appreciated.

Really struggling with the lack of documentation or results from the web.

Comment: If it is a library then it is to an external shared library that has been registered with the database and is stored in the local operating system. Talk to your DBA and ask them for documentation about the library because its probably nothing to do with Oracle; it is probably something create by the company you work for.

Comment: What does `SELECT * FROM ALL_LIBRARIES WHERE library_name = 'UTIL_XML_LIB';` output? Does the `FILE_SPEC` column correspond to a DLL on your database server? Is there documentation for that DLL?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its just a misspell?

You say that you get an exception: `SYS.UTIL_XML_LIB must be declared`

The correct name is `UTL_XML_LIB`, not `UTIL_XML_LIB`.